# Computed field value in twig template

Tags: theming, entities

I use a computed field, to calculate and store a floating value for a node. Now I want to work with this value in a twig template. When I access the field value via `{{ content.computed_field.0 }}`it outputs the correct value, say `0.22`. When I try to calculate with this value, i.e. `{% set newvalue = content.computed_field.0 * 100 %}` the page breaks (just pre-calculation twig content is outputted).

My first guess was that, for some reason, the field value is stored or read as a string (or another type?!). My DB says its a float and I don't know how to check a variable type in twig.

I tried to to use twigs `number_format()`-function : `{{ content.computed_field.0|number_format(2) }}`. This transforms the computed field to 1. I have no clue why this happens.
What am I doing wrong? Any tips or a workaround?

I use Drupal 8, Twig 1.25, and Computed Field 8.x-2.0-alpha3

Thank you in advance

Comment: Why can't you make a math in field preprocess function?

Answer (score 1):

You could try this, if your using a node template:
{{ node.computed_field.value * 100 }}